# enviar datos mediante ajax de un select

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo la siguiente lineas

```js
$(document).on('change', '#select_encuestas', function(event) {
        //alert( this.value );
        //alert("sssd");
             var x = document.getElementById("select_encuestas").value;
             //alert("id.."+x);
             console.log();
             if(x!=0){
                    $("#agregarSeccion").show();    
             }else{
                $("#agregarSeccion").hide();    
             }
            // definirEncuesta(x);
             parametros="id="+x;
                $.ajax({
                    url:'secciones_ajax.php',
                    data: parametros,
                     beforeSend: function(objeto){
                    $("#loader").html("<center><img src='loader.gif'></center>");
                    },
                    success:function(data){
                    $(".outer_div").html(data).fadeIn('slow');
                    $("#loader").html("");
                //  load(1);
                  }
            });
          event.preventDefault()
```

necesito enviar el id a la pagina  secciones_ajax pero al parecer no se envia en id.... crei que era el **Event** pero creo que no funciona asi

Comment: intenta cambiar parametros="id="+x; por parametros={id: x};

Answer (score 1):

Esta línea:

```
 parametros="id="+x;
```

Pudieras sustituirla por:

```
var parametros = $('#formulario').serialize();
```

Lo anterior para ocuparnos con el método serialize que lea todos los inputs de un formulario y se los lleve listos dentro de la var parametros

Para poder leer todos los inputs de un formulario le coloco en la etiqueta form un id en este caso formulario

```
<form id="formulario" method="POST">
```

Ya al final en tu método AJAX lo demás sigue igual, así al final no tienes que declarar uno por uno de los valores si no que se van todos juntos

Saludos y me dices si sirvió

Answer (score 1):

Ya que estas usando jquery, es mejor usarlo para todo el script. Si deseas que obtener el valor de un select haz lo siguiente:

```
$(document).on('change', '#select_encuestas', function(event) {
    //alert( this.value );
    //alert("sssd");
         var x = $("#select_encuestas option:selected").val();
         //alert("id.."+x);
         console.log();
         if(x!=0){
                $("#agregarSeccion").show();    
         }else{
            $("#agregarSeccion").hide();    
         }
        // definirEncuesta(x);
            $.ajax({
                url:'secciones_ajax.php',
                data: {id:x},
                 beforeSend: function(objeto){
                $("#loader").html("<center><img src='loader.gif'></center>");
                },
                success:function(data){
                $(".outer_div").html(data).fadeIn('slow');
                $("#loader").html("");
            //  load(1);
              }
        });
      event.preventDefault()});
```